# why we need onSaveInstanceState()?

Tags: android

In `Activity` Lifecycle, we can use `onPause()` to save screen state and release  some resources. On the other side, we can use `onResume()` to get previously saved state and reuse previous variables.

So, why we need using `onSaveInstanceState()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question. However, those method has different proposes. There're also some differences between `onPause/onResume` and `onSaveInstanceState` that are important to remember:

**You don't need to store the state everytime**

`onSavedInstanceState()` is not called when you press Home Key or press back key to leave the activity. `onPause`, on the other hand is called on those situations. So, saving the state during `onPause` is a lack of resources (your are storing the state when it is not necessary).

**onResume runs too late**

`onResume()` is called after your activity is already ready to be displayed to the user (since it is called after onStart and onCreate). So, restoring the view state during `onResume` is not a good ideia because it is already too late...

During `onCreate`, you already can access the `Bundle` previously saved. So, inside `onCreate`, you can decide if you set default content or restore the old-stored data.
You can update the view before the view is even visible. User won't notice the change.

If you restore the state during `onResume`, the view was already created and probably already visible to the user. So, he will notice the screen being re-created with default content and slowly change to the old-stored content.

**Updating view state during `onResume` can me the screen blink**

`onSavedInstanceState()` allows you to store the info you need in a `Bundle`. Then, during `onCreate`, you already can access that bundle and "create" the screen with proper content. Before the content is visible to the user.

If you try to restore whole screen state during `onResume`, you can notice the screen blinking. This will happen because whole screen was created during `onCreate` and later was updated again during `onResume`.. Even if you aren't changing the content.

Those are some of the reasons I see you really should use `onSaveInstanceState` to store the view state.

Answer (score 0):

`onSaveInstanceState()` gets called automatically and thats not the part of typical (general flow) activity lifecycle. Its called automatically by the OS when your App is in background and OS needs to kill your App to free some memory. And you also receive a `Bundle` object in it, you can put your important data in that bundle. And You receive that bundle in `OnCreate()` method when Users resumes your App from Background.

You can read about it further [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states)

Example by Android

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";
// ...


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, currentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, currentLevel);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Now in OnCreate Method you receive that bundle

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        currentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
        currentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onSaveInstanceState() Is a function that is called as part of the lifecycle.
The most common example of it is when you rotate screen and the activity gets destroyed and recreated on save instance is being called.
when it is called you can insert values (in key value format) to a bundle and then restore the activity as it was.

for example if I have a timer going down and I rotate the phone the screen will be recreated and the timer will restart unless I save it state with onSaveInstaceState()